# Any classes to connect external database in WindowsPhone8?

Tags: sql-server, c#-4.0, windows-phone-8

I've checked http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbconnection.aspx
But it seems every implementation of DbConnection cannot be used in WP8 environment.

Is there any class like Sqlconnection in WP8???

Thanks,
Jarvis

Comment: I think its a good decision from Microsoft to not support direct DB Access. Wrapping your data within a solid Service layer (most of time, using web services), will make better apps. With a bit more work, it's true

Answer (score 0):

There are none in WP8 .  All data access is through a cloud layer ala REST or some kind of http layer.  You have SQLCE on the phone, and can use SQL Lite, but there's no "Let my WP8 app hit a remove SQL database somewhere" type functionality.